# countdown in the lockscreen

Tags: ios, countdown, lockscreen

I would like to use the `countdown` in the `lockscreen` :

[image]

There is a way to use this feature ? Because I know we can interact with the lock screen for audio play but I don't find anything about how to access to this countdown.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and no. No as there is not API that will allow you to present anything on the lockscreen other than new playing info or notifications.

But you might be able misuse the [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this, but Apple will probably only all this if you .